# php jquery selecting the specific checkbox inside the while fetch_array

Tags: php, jquery, css, checkbox

I have a problem selecting specific checkbox and putting higlight css for its div inside the mysql_fetch_array

here's my code

```
$count=1;
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM thread');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  echo "<div class='row".$count."'><input type='checkebox' class='chk_box".$count."'> ".$row['title']."</div>";
  $count++; 
}

<script>
 var count= "<?php echo $count?>";
 for(var y=1;y<=count;y++){ 
$('.chk_box'+y).click(function() {
  if(this.checked) {
    $('.row'+y).addClass('backcolor');
  }
  else{
    $('.row'+y).removeClass('backcolor');
  }
 });
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed som typos, added a DOM ready function, and changed the jQuery a bit, try that ?

```
$count=1;
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM thread');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo "<div class='row".$count."'><input type='checkbox' class='chk_box".$count."'> ".$row['title']."</div>";
   $count++; 
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('[class^="chk_box"]').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('backcolor', this.checked);
    });
});
</script>​​​​​​​​​​
```

as a sidenote, attaching event handlers inside for loops is usually not a very good idea.